# sed: получить содержимое между html-тегами

Tags: html, sed

Собственно, есть html страница, нужная мне часть находится между тегами

```
<tbody id="usd_table"> и </tbody>
```

Пишу команду:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/.*<tbody id=\"usd_table\">\(.*\)<\/tbody>.*/\1/'
```

Sed обрезает все до **первого** вхождения первого тега и после **последнего** вхождения второго тега. Как сделать, чтоб обрезал после **первого** вхождения второго тега?

Comment: Используйте нормальный язык программирования, в котором есть нормальный парсер html.

Comment: @VladD я бы с радостью, но нужен bash

Comment: Эээ, ну тогда я бы на вашем месте просто сказал «нет» тому, кто дал такое задание. Рекурсивные грамматики нужно разбирать парсером, а не регулярками.

Comment: работает ли xmllint в вашем случае?  xpath `"//tbody[@id='usd_table']/node()"`

Comment: @NikolayPetrov, bash — нормальный язык программирования. но вы-то использовали sed, а не bash.

Comment: ну и традиционно: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4827341)

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто разбить на две команды

```
| sed 's/.*<tbody id=\"usd_table\">\(.*\)$/\1/g' | sed -r 's/<\/tbody>.+//'
```

Comment: группа и её подстановка во втором аргументе оператора `s` в таком случае не требуется. и второй команды не требуется. оба оператора `s` можно поместить в одну команду: `s/.*начало//;s/конец.*//`